# Theano function using individual elements of input

Tags: python, numpy, graphics, rotation, theano

I am trying to build a Theano function that takes a `T.vector` of Euler angles as input and returns a directional vector corresponding to those Euler angles. First, I take the sines and cosines of each element of the vector, then I arrange these into a rotation matrix. Finally, I multiply the directional vector `[1, 0, 0]` by this rotation matrix. The problem I am running into is that I can't multiply this NumPy array by the rotation matrix.

This is my code:

```
import theano.tensor as T
import theano
import numpy as np

euler_angles = T.vector('euler_angles', dtype=theano.config.floatX)
origin_vec = theano.shared(np.asarray([1, 0, 0],
                                      dtype=theano.config.floatX))
sinx = T.sin(euler_angles[0])
siny = T.sin(euler_angles[1])
sinz = T.sin(euler_angles[2])
cosx = T.cos(euler_angles[0])
cosy = T.cos(euler_angles[1])
cosz = T.cos(euler_angles[2])

# Create the rotation matrix
rot_matrix = np.asarray([
        [cosy*cosz, -1*sinz, cosz * siny],
        [(sinx*siny)+(cosx*cosy*sinz), cosx*cosz, (-1*cosy*sinx)+(cosx*siny*sinz)],
        [(-1*cosx*siny)+(cosy*sinx*sinz), cosz*sinx, (cosx*cosy)+(sinx*siny*sinz)]
    ])
vector = T.dot(origin_vec, rot_matrix)
get_vector = theano.function([euler_angles], vector)
```

The second-to-last line throws this error:

```
AsTensorError: ('Cannot convert [[Elemwise{mul,no_inplace}.0 Elemwise{mul,no_inplace}.0\n  Elemwise{mul,no_inplace}.0]\n [Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0 Elemwise{mul,no_inplace}.0\n  Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0]\n [Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0 Elemwise{mul,no_inplace}.0\n  Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0]] to TensorType', <type 'numpy.ndarray'>)
```

I can't think of any way to create this rotation matrix through matrix operations on the Euler angles. How can I create this function in a format that Theano can compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `theano.tensor.stacklists()`.

```
rot_matrix = T.stacklists([[...], ...])
```

Comment: Thank you! If anyone needs more information, the documentation is [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html?highlight=stacklists#theano.tensor.stacklists).

Comment: An additional question: does anyone know if Tensorflow has a corresponding function? I've looked around but I'm unable to find anything. I'm asking because I'd like to make this function usable in Keras, whether the backend is Theano or TF.